# Computed observable in knockoutjs doesn't update on change?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm currently studying knockoutjs and I was just following the tutorial on list and collection on the official website of knockoutjs, currently what I have is a dropdown that lists the items I have and then adjacent to it is a text that displays the text(price), now what I want to happen is that the text displayed should change based from the selected item of the dropdown.

Here is a jsfiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/UQskS/

Also, if you notice something wrong with my code aside from what I mention above please do advise me, for best practice or for correction.

```
// Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
    //var self = this;
    //self.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.name = name;
    this.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
    this.formattedPrice = ko.computed(function () {
        var price = this.meal().price;
        return price ? "$" + price.toFixed(2) : "None";
    }, this);
}

function ReservationsViewModel(name, meal) {
    //var self = this;
    // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
    this.availableMeals = [
        { mealId: 1, mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 47.55 },
        { mealId: 2, mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
        { mealId: 3, mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290.123 }
    ];

    //editable data
    this.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Randel", this.availableMeals[2]),
        new SeatReservation("Knockout", this.availableMeals[1])
    ]);

    //operations
    this.addSeat = function () {
        this.seats.push(new SeatReservation("", this.availableMeals[0]));
    };

    this.removeSeat = function (seat) {
        this.seats.remove(seat);
    ;}
}

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

Sir/Ma'am, your answers would be of great help. Thank you++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you really need to change from how you currently have it coded is the options binding parameters.

You are using `optionsValue` and then trying to update the id on the `meal` property. This is just going to overwrite the `mealId` property without changing the object it is referring to.

[This jsFiddle demonstrates what is going on](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/dAxQU/). Notice that you have to click the refresh link in order to force the UI to update since `mealId` is not an observable.

To fix this, you just need to bind the value directly to the selected object instead.

```
<select data-bind="
    options: $root.availableMeals,
    value: meal,
    optionsText: 'mealName',
    optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
</select>
```

Here is the updated (and working) fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/nrHcs

### Update:

If you want to use the `mealId` because you will be pulling these values from the database, then at some point you will have to do a lookup to get the other values. Either you pay the price up front, or when you are saving.

Here is an updated fiddle that shows one way of how you might accomplish this.

http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/YAMS5/

Comment: I made it that way so that I could add a 'value' attribute to the select element of my html that way I could detect the mealId selected, so for instance it goes inside the database I can use the 'mealId' for reference.

Comment: You could still use the `mealId` but just keep the property at that. Don't pass the whole object in to your reservation class.